# Why Do Electrodes Develop Equilibrium Potential?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

When we place metal electrode in solution of its ions, metal ions from metal have tendency to go into solution and ions from solution tend to enter the metal lattice. My question is what is a cause of this tendency for ions in metal lattice? Is it the same tendency which creates vapor pressure of liquids a.k.a Boltzmann distribution which allows some of metal ions (liquid molecules) that have enough energy to break metallic bonds and go into solution. If interactions with solvent or any other phase for that matter are favourable equilibrium position is more shifted towards solvation of ions (more negative electric potential of metal). Basically is Boltzmann distribution cause of tendency of ions in metal to move into solution and vice versa?

Comment: No. That has to do with electrons. Don't look it as an escape of ions. That is contingent to the ions being soluble. But it is not related to the electrochemical potential within the metals. Think of passivation, for instance. I know that this isn't satisfactory but I think it does orient you to the relevant property.

Comment: I wouldn't agree. Driving force of creating potential difference due to transfer of ions through interface is the fact that system is not in thermodynamic/chemical equilibrium. Atoms in metal lattice need to have sufficient energy to break metallic bonds, so that process can start to happen with some obersvable speed (Activation energy). Potential difference created on electrode/electrolyte difference depends on metal bond enthalpy, ionization energy, enthalpy of hydration of ions, activity of ions etc. Because of differences in chemical potential, difference in electric potential is made.